# ucry and ucrz gates in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate

I just came across ucry and ucrz gates in Qiskit. It would be great if someone has experience of using it and can explain it with an example and also with a bit of Python code.
I only know about the basic gates. I think these are not basic gates?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you provide some further detail about what you looking to learn about these gates? Are you just wondering how to implement them into a circuit? Or are you asking for a specific use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ucry`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.ucry.html), [`ucrz`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.ucrz.html), and also [`ucrx`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.ucrx.html) are **uniformly-controlled** rotation gates. What does it mean? There are 2 parts to this, the first one is a bit different and the second one is well familiar.

**The fisrt part is a special multi-controlled gate:**

1. **This uniformly controlled gate allows us to define controlled operations to be applied on the target qubit for any possible computational basis state of the control qubits.** How?
2. We set as input to the gate a list of $k$ control qubits.
3. These control qubits can be in $2^k$ computational basis states. For example, if we set $k = 2$ control qubits, then their computational basis states are $00, 01, 10, 11$.
4. For each possible computational basis state of the $k$ control qubits we define a controlled-operation to be applied on the target qubit.
5. Why it might be useful? If we set a single regular multi-controlled gate then it defines an operation to be applied on the target qubit just for 1 possible computational basis state of the control qubits. In all other cases - nothing happens. So if we want to define operations for other possible basis states of the control qubits we would need more regular controlled gates.

**The Second part - a controlled rotation:**

1. We set as input a list of desired rotation angles for each possible computational basis state of the control qubits, in the same order as explained in the previous paragraph. For example if we set `angle_list = [math.pi, math.pi/2, math.pi/3, math.pi/4]` - then for control qubits in $00$ a rotation of $\pi$ will be applied on the target qubit, for $01$ we get $\frac{\pi}{2}$, for $10$ we get $\frac{\pi}{3}$, and for $11$ we get $\frac{\pi}{4}$.
2. Note the order issues here - Qiskit uses `little-endian` notation so the most significant control qubit is the downmost control qubit in the circuit, and the leftmost bits in the computational basis bitstrings correspond to that (The example below demonstrates that).

**Qiskit implementation:**

Consider the following piece of code:

```
import math
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
from qiskit.visualization import plot_bloch_multivector

qc = QuantumCircuit(3)

qc.x(0)
qc.ucrx(angle_list = [math.pi, math.pi/2, math.pi/3, math.pi/4], q_controls = [0,1], q_target = 2)

display(qc.draw())
display(plot_bloch_multivector(Statevector(qc)))
```

And the output:

[image]

The input state of the control qubits (`q0 + q1`) to the `ucrx` gate is $01$, and therefore the x-rotation being applied on `q2` is $\frac{\pi}{2}$.
You can modify the code and run it with different input states / angles / qubits to get an intuition for all this long explanation.

**Edit - Decompostion of uniformly-controlled gates:**

[This](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0410066.pdf) paper explains the decomposition of these gates. In high level and freely speaking - a uniformly-controlled gate "shrinks" $2^k$ multi-controlled gates to 1 notation block.

In the example that I gave above the high-level decomposition of the `ucrx` gate is:

[image]

The code I have wrote for this is:

```
import math
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library.standard_gates.rx import RXGate

k = 2
rotations = [math.pi, math.pi/2, math.pi/3, math.pi/4]

qc = QuantumCircuit(3)
qc.ucrx(angle_list = rotations, q_controls = [0,1], q_target = 2)

qcd = QuantumCircuit(3)
count = 0
for theta in rotations:
    binary = bin(count)[2:]
    bitstring = ('0' * (k - len(binary))) + binary 
    u = RXGate(theta = theta).control(num_ctrl_qubits = k, ctrl_state = bitstring)
    qcd.append(u, qargs = [i for i in range(k+1)])
    count += 1

display(qc.draw())
display(qcd.draw())
```

It can be modified for different types of uniformly-controlled gates / more control qubits etc.

Comment: Thank you @Ohad for your response. If I want to know the circuit of the Ucrx gate, then what should I do?

Comment: I have edited my answer with an update regarding the circuit decomposition of `ucrx` and other uniformly-controlled gates.

Comment: This is a really  great help. Thank you @Ohad.